# How can I make IntelliJ CE's Java syntax highlighting more colorful?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, accessibility, syntax-highlighting

IntelliJ CE provides a lot fewer colors in its syntax highlighting than Visual Studio Code. With the exception of a few key words, everything in IntelliJ is grey, while VSC highlights method calls, class names, keywords, and annotations with different colors.  Because I have low vision, VSC's colorful highlighting helps me code much faster.
Is there any way to either 1) import my syntax highlighting settings from VSC into IntelliJ CE or 2) get an extension that colors methods, variables, types, and keywords differently?
The colors in IntelliJ don't have to be exactly the same as they were in VSC, as long as they're not all grey.

Comment: [Material UI](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui) plugin provides some of the most popular themes for IntelliJ IDEA. Check it out.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ offers plenty of plugins to do this for you. Alternatively, in Settings, you can customize the colors on your own. I use the [Monokai Pro](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13643-monokai-pro-theme) plugin with a few modifications of my own.

Answer (score 1):

I use this plugin for intelliJ: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10559-gapstyle-color-scheme, maybe could help you.

for install a new plugin in Intellij: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html